# How can one create .dll files with NASM?

Tags: c++, dll, assembly, nasm

Is is possible to assemble Assembly code into .dll files with NASM assembler?
I need this because I want to link a .dll file containing Assembly code and a .dll file containing C++ code together, and load that .dll with JNI (Java Native Interface) that will call the C++ functions which are just wrappers for the Assembly functions.
Compiling the C++ & Assembly code into two separate .dll modules, calling the "Assembly .dll code" from the "C++ .dll code" is also a possibility.

Best regards,
Benjamin.

Answer (score 2):

NASM just creates an object (.o/.obj) file, right? Why not link that into your C++ DLL by specifying it as an additional input on either the linker command line or the project properties?

Comment: D'oh! I can't believe I didn't think of that! :O Silly me.. either way, thanks a bunch :).

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dll with nasm and use alink as your linker. 
In your source use the following lines for every function in your dll:
global myfunc

export myfunc

You need to provide a _dllmain function that gets called upon initialisation. 
Just return 1 in eax and retn 12 because you need to cleanup 3 args which aren't used here.

Assemble with -fobj (omf) then link with -dll added to the pe and GUI options